# Failing to push object into array, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't understand why the following line is failing.

```
    locations.push(location);
```

I am trying to create an array (locations) filled with location objects (annotations, latitude, longitude). Annotations is also an array, but filled with annotation objects (ID, smartzone, timestamp, entry, action).

Here's the code snippet.

```
var map;    
var locations = [];

function Location() {
    this.annotations = []; /* Array of annotations */
    this.latitude    = null; /* Location latitude    */
    this.longitude   = null; /* Location longitude   */
}

function Annotation() {
    this.ID        = null;
    this.smartzone = null;
    this.timestamp = null;
    this.entry     = null;
    this.action    = null;
}

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.73, -84.49),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    $.getJSON("http://www.site.com/pathto/map/json.php", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {

            //alert(val.ID);
            var location = new Location();
            var annotation = new Annotation();

            if (locations.length === 0) {

                annotation.ID        = val.ID;
                annotation.smartzone = val.smartzone;
                annotation.timestamp = val.timestamp;
                annotation.entry     = val.entry;
                annotation.action    = val.action;

                location.annotations.push(annotation);

                location.latitide  = val.latitude;
                location.longitude = val.longitude;

                locations.push(location); /* This is the line that fails */

            } else {

                var locationExists = false;

                for (var i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {

                    if (val.latitude == locations[i].latitude && val.longitude == locations[i].longitude) { 

                        locationExists = true; 
                    }   
                }

                if (locationExists) {

                    annotation.ID        = val.ID;
                    annotation.smartzone = val.smartzone;
                    annotation.timestamp = val.timestamp;
                    annotation.entry     = val.entry;
                    annotation.action    = val.action;

                    locations[i].annotations.push(annotation);

                } else {

                    annotation.ID        = val.ID;
                    annotation.smartzone = val.smartzone;
                    annotation.timestamp = val.timestamp;
                    annotation.entry     = val.entry;
                    annotation.action    = val.action;

                    location.annotations.push(annotation);

                    location.latitide  = val.latitude;
                    location.longitude = val.longitude;
                    //locations.push(location); /* Same problem */
                }
            }           
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: What do you mean by it "fails"? Fails how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that this is correct:

```
for (var i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {
```

`annotations` isn't defined anywhere. so this loop should never execute.

This means that `i` will always be `0` when you get here:

```
locations[i].annotations.push(annotation)
```

Which honestly I don't know why you are doing anyway as the `i` counter, even if working, doesn't seem to have any relation to the index in the `locations` array.  I would think you need some counter to be incremented with each execution of `$.each()` loop.

Finally, it seems odd that in some cases you want to add data to `locations` using `push()` while in other cases you try to use a counter (i.e. `locations[i]`) to indicate where you are adding items in the array.  I would think you need to be consistent here.

To me the logic flow in the loop might better be done like this:

```
// have a means to store location hash with value for index location in locations
// this prevents you from having to iterate over locations array for each data element to see if location already exists
// this would be defined at the beginning along with locations
var locationMap = {};


// this would take place inside your getJSON success function
// counter for incrementing location index
var locationCount = 0;
$.each(...) { // iterate the data
    // create simple hash of lat/long
    var locationHash = val.latitude + val.longitude;
    // determine if location already exists
    if(locationMap[locationHash] == undefined) { // this is new location
        var location = new Location();
        var location.annotations[0] = new Annotation();

        // not shown - populate location and annotation property values 

        // add to locations array
        locations[locationCount] = location;

        // add hash to location map
        locationMap[locationHash] = locationCount;

        // increment location counter
        locationCount++;
     } else {
        var locationIndex = locationMap[locationHash];
        var annotation = new Annotation;

        // not shown - populate annotation property values

        // add new annotation to existing location
        location[locationIndex].annotations.push(annotation);
     }
}
```

Comment: @geschwe1 Though I think this will solve your problem, I would also suggest that, if you have control over the JSON data being produced, you should strongly consider formatting the data structure on the server side so that you can better consume it. There would be no reason you couldn't return the data exactly as you need it from the server, without having the need to transform it in javascript. I would suggest that if the data doesn't change often, you might even have a cached JSON representation you can server up from the server to avoid calculating this data structure with each AJAX request